# Android Black Theme vs White Theme

Tags: android, themes, lcd, power-management

Is there a performance impact, especially with regard to battery performance, if we switch from the default black theme of android to white or another colour?

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: You want to make an informed choice as a developer

Answer (score 0):

If the screen is LCD white light consumes less power than the black.

Comment: It actually depends on the resting state of the LCD. Some tests show LCDs using less power when black, and some less power when white. I don't think I would really worry about it, with CRTs the difference between the two was something large (like 20%). For LCDs, I'm finding stats that show something more like 6% in either direction. Read here: http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=fact-or-fiction-black-is&page=2

Answer (score 0):

What Chimmy said, plus for AMOLED displays black uses less power as far as I know. The Nexus One is AMOLED and Samsung Galaxy S is Super AMOLED.